# how can we append/update sub-document of collction in MongoDB using MongoDB Java driver?

Tags: java, mongodb

My mongoDB document is as following.

```
{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "551e34ddbb4fd7cc3a0849d0"
  },
  "192_168_100_12": [
    {
      "User_Login1": [
        {
          "time": {
            "$date": -23224339068000
          },
          "message": "leneghadik"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "User_Login": [
        {
          "time": {
            "$date": -23224339068000
          },
          "message": "leneghadik"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "User_Login": [
        {
          "time": {
            "$date": -23224339068000
          },
          "message": "my ja"
        }
      ]
    },
    {
      "User_Login1": {
        "time": {
          "$date": -23224339068000
        },
        "message": "my ja"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

I want to append new object into `"User_Login1"` using java. How can i achieve that?
I tried many method but it didn't work and i end up appending data into`"192_168_100_12"`.

My code for appending was as below.

```
BasicDBObject event = new BasicDBObject("time", curDate).append("message", "my ja");
node_info.update(new BasicDBObject(), new BasicDBObject("$push", new BasicDBObject("192_168_100_12", new BasicDBObject("User_Login1", event))));
```

Please help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
BasicDBObject event = new BasicDBObject("time", curDate).append("message", "my ja");
BasicDBObject data = new BasicDBObject("$push", 
                               new BasicDBObject("192_168_100_12$User_Login1", event));
collection.update(new BasicDBObject(), data);
```

This will probably do your work.

Comment: Nope. Not working. creating new document of name 192_168_100_12$User_Login1